# Position fixed element moves when iframe being resized

Tags: html, css, iframe, css-position, fixed

I have an `iframe` that's always at the bottom left of the parent page and within this `iframe` there's an element that's also at the bottom left of the `iframe`. So the result is this element is always at the bottom left of the window which is what I want.

This is achieved with **CSS** below:

```
iframe {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
}

#my-element { // this would be in the style sheet of iframe
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

The problem is when my `iframe` is resized, e.g. from `height` = *100px* to *500px*, my element suddenly jumps up for about 0.1 second then go back to its proper position. I think this is because when browser re-render my `iframe`, it display my element first then see the css rules of `bottom:0px` thus causing the 0.1 second jump.

> **Is there any way I can avoid this jump?**

Comment: Can you make a minimal working snippet?

Comment: @SahilDhir   I'd love to, but when I try to do that with jsfiddle, I don't know how to create an iframe there. Maybe I can post something that people can run locally.